# How to configure Fluent NHibernate automapping so it makes separate hbm for sub classes?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

This question might seems a bit strange at first but there's a legacy project that is working this way and I want to know if there's a way to generate its hbm documents using Fluent Nhibernate.
We have a parent class which is not an abstract class .Something like this:

```
    [Entity("EmployeeTable")]
    public class Employee
    {
       //Memebers of Employee
    }
```

and it has some subclasses.The purpose of these subclasses is merely for code re-usability and as you can see these are some views (Summaries) to represent some information.

```
[Entity("EmployeeType1View")]
public class EmployeeType1:Employee
{
//Memebers of EmployeeType1
}

[Entity("EmployeeType2View")]
public class EmployeeType2:Employee
{
//Memebers of EmployeeType2
}
```

So here is the question : is there a way that we can tell fluent nhibernate not to take this inheritance hierarchy into account or in another word to tell it to generate separate hbm file for each of these classes?

Comment: if you only write ClassMaps for the subclasses then it wont exist for FNH. Is that what you want?

Comment: No unfortunately it's not possible.First ,because we really want to map the parent class and second we are using auto-mapping

Answer (score 1):

unfortunatly FNH can not write subclass maps individually. You could however alter the mapping after writing it to disc.

```
var model = new FluentNHibernate.Automapping.AutoPersistenceModel();
// add assembly and the like to model
model.WriteMappingsTo(path);

forech(var baseclass in classesWithSubclasses)
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(baseclass.getType().FullName + ".hbm.xml");
    // use xpath to separate the subclassmapping in its own file
}
```